# Crawl Desired/precise data from site using nutch-solr

Tags: search, solr, web-crawler, fetch, nutch

While running nutch, I am getting all the data. This is what I do not want. I wants to fetch data according to div class and div id. I mean that I do not want to fetch all data but data according to my need .Is it possible ??

Comment: you may want to check https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-978 and http://www.atlantbh.com/precise-data-extraction-with-apache-nutch/

Comment: @Jayendra:Thanks for thq quick reply.I followed second link(atlantbh.com)and I am getting this error
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: url

However when I was not going for precise data extraction, at that  time, I was not getting such error and solr console could display results.
Why am I getting this error with precise data extraction ??.Please help me

Comment: @Jayendra: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field:this error is showing in tomcat-solr log file and ERROR solr.SolrIndexer - java.io.IOException: Job failed! in nutch log file. please help me

Comment: @KamalKishore You have a bug in your schema.xml config file. You have set the <uniqueKey> field to "url" but you haven't added it to the <fields> list.

Comment: @nimeshjm:I have checked this. The field <url> is present in the schema.xml in nutch and  solr. If the field was missing, then I would have got the same error when I was not fetching precise data(when i was fetching all data). Please help me..

Comment: @KamalKishore can you post your schema.xml file?

Comment: @nimeshjm:can you give me you mail id or how do I send you the schema file ?

Comment: Put your schema.xml file contents in a http://pastebin.com/ and share the url.

Comment: here the link of the schema.xml file http://pastebin.com/p0KKPm89. In the file , I have added two field based on precise data extraction tutorial.
 <!-- xpath filter fields -->
        <field name="articleTitle" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true" />
        <field name="articleAuthor" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true" />. here the nutch-site.xml file http://pastebin.com/nT5dkRSz. here solindex-mapping.xml link http://pastebin.com/C067fynd.If you need any other file then do let me know

Comment: here link to xpathfilter-conf.xml file- http://pastebin.com/e4FeJbky

Comment: When you call the bin/crawl script, are you using a clearing the crawl directory or re-using an existing one from a previous crawl?

Comment: @nimeshjm:I am deleting the previous directory by rm command.Everytime I call bin/crawl script, I delete the previous crawl folder from nutch home directory. Did you find any flaws in schema or any other file ?. Shall I send you any other file for further testing ?

Comment: @KamalKishore This might be a long shot but I deployed a new instance of Nutch in a new server and I started getting that error. In the end I remembered that I had changed the bin/crawl script to fix a bug with the solr indexing task. Have a go and let me know how it went: http://pastebin.com/uZTNJPuE